# pylint reports maybe-no-member error for data loaded via simplejson

Tags: python, pylint, simplejson

When I run the following block of code with pylint, I get no errors.

```
import json
for key, value in json.loads('{"foo":"bar"}').items():
    print(key, value)
```

Upon switching out `json` with `simplejson` and then running pylint, I get the error:

```
Instance of 'bool' has no 'items' member (but some types could not be inferred) (maybe-no-member)
```

From comparing the infered result of `astroid` for both simplejson.loads & json.loads - it appears that even when both json & simplejson are compiled with the c_speedups, astroid picks up the python version of the [scan_once](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/scanner.py#L68) function when dealing with the `simplejson` library, and the c version when dealing with the `json` library.

```
import astroid.builder
builder = astroid.builder.AstroidBuilder()
ast = builder.string_build("""
import simplejson
import json
x = json.loads('"test"')
y = simplejson.loads('"test"')
""")

json_assignment, simplejson_assignment = list(ast.get_children())[2:]
print "json:", list(json_assignment.get_children())[-1].infered()
print "simplejson:", list(simplejson_assignment.get_children())[-1].infered()
```

Running the above code outputs:

```
json: [YES]
simplejson: [YES, <Const(NoneType) l.97 [simplejson.scanner] at Ox102720290>, <Const(bool) l.99 [simplejson.scanner] at Ox1027207d0>, <Const(bool) l.101 [simplejson.scanner] at Ox102720d10>]
```

I'm not sure why `astroid` has different behavior when inferring the return types of `simplejson.loads` & `json.loads` - but the above implies that the scenario with the `json` library might be getting past pylint accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

`Pylint` can't know that the result type of `json.loads` will be `dict`, because it depends on the input string. It is typical that a dynamical code like getattr, setattr etc. can not be introspected deep enough in a predictable short time and therefore is guessed, not introspected.

Comment: What is a novice python programmer using Pylint to do in this situation?  Is there a way to get Pylint to ignore certain conditions?

Comment: @condiosluzverde: (I have not used pylint since that.) A novice Python programmer can start with use [Flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8). It helps also very much and and it is without obtrusive *false positive* messages (almost). I use it because I decided to imitate [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) style (a big project, heavy using dynamic code) I use similarly `max-line-length` a little longer than 79 and `exclude=some,filenames,or,directories` for files that are not written by me.

Comment: A good code can be easily without warnigs. Sometimes I use `#NOQA` comments for unused variables that will be useful for debugging. Flake8 is so fast and unobtrusive that in can be used as editor plugin after every save. I prefer no warnings before commit. Pylint can be sometimes used as a second tool. It can find more bugs, for the price much more false positives, but I also made more bugs because I thought at pylint, not at the code while writing.